# What kind of situation does "restlessness" refer to in the passage?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> I was studying quite hard actually everyday and the weather  was very hot outside but I kept studying and everyday, one of my friends would call me and say: "Hey Jane we're going to the beach today, do you want to come?" or, "We're going away to the coast for the weekend to go surfing, you should come with us", every time I had to say "no, I'm sorry, I can't because I have to study". So I was being very good and staying focused. Until finally, I think it was about a week away from my exams and I was starting to feel really ***restless*** and frustrated when I heard that an old friend of mine was back in town from abroad. He called me up and what could I say? I really wanted to catch up with him because it had been ages since we'd hung out together. He was only in town for a couple of days so of course I put my study on hold and we went out and had a great night.

What kind of *restlessness* is that Jane felt? Is that she just can't wait to see her old friend and she's excited, hence fidgeting, or she's nervous that the time she would spend hanging out with him could cost her a good exam ?

Thanks in advance for all who will take the time to answer

Answer (score 2):

In this instance I get the impression that Jane's restlessness is not caused by her old friend being in town.

I think this because Jane says that she is already feeling restless after all of the time she's been inside instead of spending time with her friends.

When she hears an old friend is back in town it made the feelings of restlessness a lot stronger to the point that she could no longer sit at home and study.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in my repy, I had to deal with the annoying issue in connection when I was about to ask : Don't you think that preceding sentence - *"so I was being good and staying focused"* indicates that she was actually happy with the condition she was in ?

Comment: Then I spotted the mistake that I've failed to notice the sequence of events, so now your explanation makes perfect sense !

Answer (score 1):

The pattern

{x} was beginning to happen} **when** {y} occurred

(I was *starting to feel* restless **when** I *heard* my friend was back in town)

means that X was already underway and then Y took place.

> I was starting to make dinner when there came a knock at the door.
>
> I was just falling asleep when the phone rang.

So, Jane has already been feeling restless when she learns that her friend is in town.